# How to input these trim, type & bleed sizes into indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have the following specs but I have no idea how to create a new document in InDesign:

- Type depth – 70mm
- Type width – 262mm
- Trim depth – 87mm
- Trim width – 278mm
- Bleed depth – 97mm
- Bleed width – 289mm

Answer (score 1):

**278mm x 87mm document**

**8mm margins all sides** 
*(Trim depth/width minus Type depth/width leaves 16mm vertical and 16mm horizontal. Divide that by 2 to get each side... 8mm - this is the margin.)* As it's used here, "Type" seems to refer to what is more commonly referred to as "live area" or "safe zone".

**5.5mm bleed all sides** 
*(Bleed depth/width minus Trim depth/width leaves 10mm vertical and 11mm horizontal, divide that by 2 to get each side and you get 5mm verticals and 5.5mm horizontals. So round up to 5.5mm - this is the bleed area. You can never have too much bleed, so rounding up is preferred.)*